# Group by Map Value Item

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
Map<String, Set<Plugin>> map;
```

I want to convert this to

```
Map<Plugin, Set<String>>
```

The aim here is to list plugins with their strings keys. Plugin objects are being reused accord different map values. And this is the basis of the grouping.

#### What Did I try?

```
Map<Set<Plugin>, Set<String>> result = map.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, 
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```

But I don't want this. I want to group for each `Plugin` object.

Comment: in that answer, there is a `List` that is the value, you are using a `Set`, it's very easy do make it work for your case too

Comment: Thanks @Eugene your answer just worked.